# Next JS Redirect Preserve SEO

Tags: reactjs, next.js, seo, head

I have a page called `/work` that contains a load or projects and their details. Individual projects don't have their own page as all their details are shown on the work page.

My goal is to:

1. Go to a specific project on the work page with the URL.
2. That URL has SEO (head tags) for that specific project, rather than the work page head tags.

I know I could use queries `/work?id=foo` but what I really want is that unique SEO. So when I share `/work?id=foo` on social media I get the SEO for Foo not for the work page.

So my second idea was to create a project page `/work/foo` that has its own head tags and then redirect to `/work?id=foo`. Crawlers scrape the Foo head tags and the user gets redirected to Foo on work.

This isn't the most elegant solution so was wondering if anyone else has a better one? Thanks!

Comment: _"create a project page `/work/foo` that has its own head tags and then redirect to `/work?id=foo`"_ - Why would you redirect in that scenario? Why not just use the project page `/work/foo` for each specific project?

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect from `/work/foo` to `/work?id=foo`, crawlers will in most cases take the head tags from `/work?id=foo`, so I'm pretty sure this won't work. If you really do not want to have separate pages, I'd say your best option is rendering all the different head elements, including all of the open-graph and Twitter meta tags depending on the query, like this:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const { query } = useRouter();

<Head>
<title>{query && query === "query1" ? "Title for Query 1" : "Default Title"}
</title>
</Head>
```

Which would ***probably*** display all the social meta tags on social media. Still, you have no quarantee that crawlers from all the different social media platforms will respect query params and not just crawl the base page without query params which would have all the default meta tags.

And more importantly, this way browsers will most likely only index and crawl one [***canonical***](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls=) version of this page, and hence ignore all the other query params, even if you use redirects.

If you really care about SEO and not just displaying correct meta tags, I would create separate pages for all the different projects. If you only care about displaying right meta on social media, you could try the solution above and check if all the social media platforms display the information correctly with tools like: https://metatags.io/

Comment: I ended up briefly landing on the page /work/foo but then almost immediately redirecting, so the page technically exists for the crawlers to scrape the head tags but the user barely notices. Not the best solution, I'll let you know how it goes! Thanks :D

Comment: @Luke You could also not redirect automatically and display a button like 'View '  which would redirect on click